# How can I determine the region for a public AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know I can determine the region for AWS S3 buckets I own by doing:

```
aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket <my-bucket>
```

but how can I determine the region for a public access bucket (which clearly I do not own)?

If I try to access one of the AWS Open Data buckets like noaa-goes16:

```
$ aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket noaa-goes16
```

I get:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketLocation operation: Access Denied
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yeah, you would think this would be easier to figure out, but here's the method I use:

```
$ curl -sI https://noaa-goes16.s3.amazonaws.com | grep bucket-region
```

which returns:

```
x-amz-bucket-region: us-east-1
```

Comment: BTW, it works with any bucket, private or public.

Comment: wow, this was super helpful, tyvm

Answer (score 7):

Any objects returned from the bucket will respond with a `x-amz-bucket-region` header which contains the buckets region.

In addition by running a head command `curl --head $BUCKET_NAME.s3.amazonaws.com` against your bucket you can see the above header to identify the region your bucket is in.

Comment: I actually like this answer better than the one I supplied, because it's just one command instead of two, and easier to remember!